# Postgres slow bitmap heap scan

Tags: postgresql

I have tables `messages` `phones` with around 6M rows. And this query perfomance is very poor

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.number, t1.name, t1.gender
        FROM messages t1
        INNER JOIN phones t2 ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
        INNER JOIN regions t6 ON t6.id = t1.region_id
        WHERE t2.number IS NOT NULL AND t1.entity AND NOT t2.type AND t1.region_id = 50
        ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 100
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result: http://explain.depesz.com/s/Pd6D

Btree indexes on all colums in where condition. Primary keys on all `id` colums, foreign keys in `messages` table on `parent_id` and `region_id` as well. Vacuum on all tables runned too.

But over 15sec on just 100 rows is too slow. What is wrong?

Postgres 9.3, ubuntu 13.10, cpu 2x 2.5Ghz, 4gb ram, pg config http://pastebin.com/mPVH1YJi

Comment: Thankyou for an excellent question with all the info needed. If I could +10 instead of +1 I would.

Comment: It's not 15 seconds for 100 rows, at all.

It's 15 seconds for 498 rows (the result of the hash join node, 5th inward). That's where the cost is, the rest is just minor work. I'd be interested in the results of lowering random_page_cost and re-running; also what plan is produced when - for testing - you do `SET enable_hashjoin = off`. So far I suspect an appropriate composite index may be what'll be needed - I'd like to see the `\d` output for the relevant table indexes (no need for the columns) to be sure.

Comment: Anyway, if you comment here after editing with that info I should be able to follow up. Got to run.

Comment: I set random_page_cost = 2.0 and enable_hashjoin = off

Comment: It's much better now http://explain.depesz.com/s/Ta3 Thank you. All rows around 1 sec, more than enough for me. I can't set composite indexes because where condition, select statement and join tables changes dynamically all time.

Comment: `enable_hashjoin = off` is *not* a long-term solution. See the documentation. It's a debugging tool. You should adjust your planner params to more accurately reflect the real cost of random I/O on your system. Since you're doing index-only scans, make sure autovacuum runs a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends on your read vs. write load, but one solution may be to create composite indexes for the most common / general cases.

For example, BTREE(parent_id, region_id) to turn that heap scan into an index scan would be huge. Since you have dynamic queries, there might be a few other combinations of composite indexes you might need for other queries, but I would recommend using only two columns in your composite indexes for now (as each query is different). Note that BTREE(parent_id, region_id) can also be scanned when only parent_id is needed, so there is no need to carry a BTREE(parent_id) index as well.